# What is consuming the memory on SLES?

Tags: memory, sles

```
SERVER:~ # free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           31G        26G       4.5G        98M         0B       1.0G
-/+ buffers/cache:        25G       5.4G
Swap:         4.0G        68M       3.9G
SERVER:~ #
SERVER:~ # uptime
 07:59am  up 45 days 23:03,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
SERVER:~ #
```

So there is literally no extra process running that can consume the memory.

Already issued a "echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" but it was only 3G->to 1G cached RAM.

I think slowly something is lying about the memory usage.

If I rebooot the server, it will be ok, but in a few dozens of days later... all the memory is consumed again and even swap usage is starting to get bigger.

Before stopping the processes (for a custom software) I didn't seen anything from the "ps" command that says, a process is using high memory. Nothing.

**The question:** how to detect, what is using up all the memory? Is it a memory leak?

Comment: try `top -o +%MEM ` and observe the memory used by the processes.

Answer (score -1):

Try running `free -g` to see how much of the "used" memory is really just "cached".  Cached memory will free up when needed.

Comment: We are already looking at the output of `free` - `-g` just changes the units displayed.